# Firebase Crashlytics stuck waiting for app

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, crashlytics

I'm currently trying to set up Firebase Crashlytics for a Flutter iOS app. I followed the instructions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=flutter) and added a button to my app that will throw an exception when it is pressed:

```
        TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              throw Exception();
            },
            child: Text("Trigger Error",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error,
                  fontSize: 18,
                )))
```

I have the error handler set like this:

```
  // Pass all uncaught "fatal" errors from the framework to Crashlytics
  FlutterError.onError = (errorDetails) {
    FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError(errorDetails);
  };
```

I set a breakpoint in the VSCode debugger in the error handler and when I press the button I can see that `recordFlutterError` is getting called. However, the only thing I see even after a couple of days of waiting is this:

[image: Firebase Crashlytics waiting for app]

I went into XCode and set the flag for debug logging as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=flutter#expandable-1) but I don't know where to see the debug logs.

Any ideas as to what can be happening?

EDIT: I forgot to mention I also added the async handler:

```
  // Global error catcher for async functions
  // https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/errors
  PlatformDispatcher.instance.onError = (error, stack) {
    showErrorToast(error);
    FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(error, stack, fatal: true);
    return true;
  };
```

However, I know its not hitting the async error handler because of the breakpoint I set in `FlutterError.onError`.

Answer (score 0):

did you add the async error handler as well ?

this one

PlatformDispatcher.instance.onError = (error, stack) {
// If you wish to record a "non-fatal" exception, please remove the "fatal" parameter
FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(error, stack, fatal: true);
return true;
};

try to do some overflow exceptions, those will also appear in the crashlytics reports

Comment: I also have the async handler, I updated my question. However, I know it's not the async handler because I see my breakpoint getting hit in the debugger.